# In a function with a declared empty variable, how does a switch statement automatically assign its return value to the empty variable?

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement, return, conditional-statements

all. I'm fairly new to JavaScript - currently trying to understand the switch statement. I'm having a problem understanding how I still got a return value when I did no assignments to my `result` variable. The switch statement is nested in a function.

```
function caseInSwitch(val) {
  let result = "";
  switch(val) {
    case 1:
      return "alpha";
      break;
    case 2:
      return "beta";
      break;
    case 3:
      return "gamma";
      break;
    case 4:
      return "delta";
      break;
  }

  return result;  
}

caseInSwitch(1);
```

I expect `result` to be an empty string `""`, but it shows the following value immediately... without any assignments...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `return`ing in the switch statement. In the case where `val` equals `1`, the switch statement never gets past case 1. The function doesn't `return result`, it executes `return "alpha"`.

That return statement terminates the function:

```js
function caseInSwitch(val) {
  console.log("1: function start. Val:", val);

  let result = "";
  
  console.log("2: before switch");
  switch(val) {
    case 1:
      console.log("3: before return alpha");
      return "alpha";
      console.log("4: after return alpha");
      break;
    case 2:
      return "beta";
      break;
    case 3:
      return "gamma";
      break;
    case 4:
      return "delta";
      break;
  }
  console.log("5: after switch");

  return result;  
}

var finalResult = caseInSwitch(1);
console.log("Final result:", finalResult);
```

As you can see, only statements `1-3` get logged.

The `return` statement in the switch also means the `break`s are redundant:

```
switch(val) {
    case 1:
        return "alpha";
    case 2:
        return "beta";
    case 3:
        return "gamma";
    case 4:
        return "delta";
}
```

Those `break` statements are only necessary to terminate the case, if you're not returning out of the case:

```
let variable = "";
switch(val) {
    case 1:
        variable = "alpha";
        break;
    case 2:
        variable = "beta";
        break;
    case 3:
        variable = "gamma";
        break;
    case 4:
        variable = "delta";
        break;
}
console.log(variable);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a bunch! You gave more than enough information. I'm really grateful. Basically, in a function, the `return` statement terminates the function wherever it is.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple, you are passing 1 as the value for `val` in caseInSwitch. In the switch block, 1 is matched with case 1 and the function returns alpha. Keep in mind the return in the switch block, makes the control return from the function itself and not just from the switch block